# Convert arrays of array to set of arrays

Tags: ruby, arrays, set

I have an array of arrays and want to filter all arrays which have the same elements, which might only differ in their order.

`[[1,0,1],[1,1,0],[2,3,5]] => [[1,0,1],[2,3,5]]`

or similiar. Maybe I should use the [Set](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html) class for this? But maybe this can also be achieved with another method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At this moment all the answers use *O(n log n)* `sort` as uniqueness function. A histogram (frequency counter) is *O(n)*:

```
require 'facets/enumerable/frequency'
xss = [[1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 0], [2, 3, 5]]
xss.uniq(&:frequency)
#=> [[1, 0, 1], [2, 3, 5]]
```

Note however, that `sort` is a core optimized method and overall it will probably perform better.

Answer (score 10):

```
[[1,0,1],[1,1,0],[2,3,5]].uniq{|i| i.sort}
```

or

```
[[1,0,1],[1,1,0],[2,3,5]].uniq(&:sort)
```

Output:

```
[[1, 0, 1], [2, 3, 5]]
```

`sort` will make sure all sub-arrays are in the same order, and `uniq` gets rid of redundant items.

Answer (score 2):

This should do it.

```
require 'set'

set = Set.new
set << [1,0,1].sort
set << [1,1,0].sort
set << [2,3,5].sort

set.each do |e|
  puts e.to_s
end
```

Comment: This will require recoding every time the sub-arrays change.

Answer (score 0):

```
require 'set'

a = [[1,0,1],[1,1,0],[2,3,5]]

set = Set.new

a.map {|x| set << x.sort}
b = set.to_a

=> [[0, 1, 1], [2, 3, 5]]
```

Comment: This is doing a `uniq` by hand when that abstraction is available in the core... the upper abstraction you can use, the better (more declarative, less verbose, usually faster).